# Sound and cursor not working

Tags: sound, cursor

I was using my laptop and it went off due to power problems, on switching it on after lights came back, I could not see the cursor and couldn't hear sound when playing music, and then the cursor and sound comes back after 20 minutes of using the laptop. This now happens every time I restart my machine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The `tmp` folder had been accidentally deleted. I recreated and rebooted and the problem was fixed.